# PHP does modifying strings copy of update it

Tags: php, string, performance, pointers

I am going over a script making as many optimizations as possible, micro-optimizations even, but fortunately this question doesn't revolve around the necessity of such methods, more an understanding of what PHP is doing.

```
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
```

When running this line, what I would like to know is whether internally the value returned is a new string (i.e. a modified copy) or the same value in memory, but updated.

If the line looked like this:

```
$sql2 = rtrim($sql1, ',');
```

Then I wouldn't be asking, however because it is a modification of the same variable, I am wondering if PHP overwrites it with a modified copy, or updates the same value in memory.

For performance reasons, I need to run the same operations over a millions times in as short a time as possible, which is why I am really obsessing over every tiny detail.

This question isn't just for the example above, but for string manipulation in general.

Comment: Well a function has a return value that isn't a reference so it's almost certainly a new variable. The real question though is **why are you writing sql strings?** =). It's implied from the above your sql is quite likely insecure/exploitable. Alternatively: **why does it matter?** Whatever the answer it won't change your code or the performance. If you are *really* interested in performance profile the code and don't waste time optimizing something which takes 0.001% of execution time. If the code has already been profiled and you're eeking out the last few m% - show that's the case.

Comment: The sql being created is used in a prepared statement later on.  The reason it is dynamic is because the columns are dynamic.  Also that 0.001% matters, because it and everything else in the script will be looped.  Also the 1 mill operations is a small scale, the source is a 200MB file, so thats around 1 mill (lines), but the file can be several GB.

Comment: You realize it'd be easier to help you optimize the entire operation you're doing, opposed to telling you how to improve 0.0001% of everything? From what I've read, I can safely claim you're most likely doing many things wrong and that gain vs effort in optimizing what you asked for is negligible.

Comment: PHP creates a new memory location internally that contains the result from the function call, then assigns that to the variable $sql, freeing up the memory used by the old value; but this isn't something you should need to try optimising.... if you really need to know what it's doing, use VLD

Comment: If your code is all in one giant file, you'll probably get better optimisation by splitting it down into lots of smaller files that you only include when they're actually needed: one of the biggest overheads in core PHP is memory allocation/deallocation (hence all the buzz about phpng), so anything that can reduce memory usage is a benefit

Comment: @MarkBaker If thats the case then thats the answer, I'll accept it if you post it.  Maybe elaborate for records sake.  The example I gave was a small part of the script.  For most of the application I use Doctrine2, but in this specific case I am trying to be as direct as possible.  I just needed to be aware of what PHP was doing.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to avoid any statements; ifs or function calls, that only apply to a single case.  For instance I try to find alternatives to checking if a loop has reached the end as I have benchmarked if statements and array functions. While the execution time is negligible,  it still adds up.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to explain that optimizing string copy in memory is not important, your algorithm is. You're striving to optimize performance, yet you disregard the fact that what you optimize is one of the most inexpensive operations - copy from one memory location to another - it's extremely fast. It doesn't add up, even if there are millions of iterations. It's irrelevant, and your time is going to be wasted. What you SHOULD focus on is optimizing your entire algorithm and the file, not string copying.

Comment: @N.B. I appreciate that, but I was more interested in how PHP handles it opposed to how to optimize my application, I tried to explain that at the beginning.  I just needed to know if string manipulation was something I needed to worry about.  As you have stated, it is not, so thats the answer, so claim your tick and +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your specific Q: strings are stored in internal structures called ZVALs and ZVALs do a lazy copy, that is doing a copy references the same ZVAL and bumps its reference count.  Updating the string decrements the reference count on the ZVAL (and garbage collects the sting when the count is zero). On update, a new ZVAL is created pointing to the new value.

Now to the general misconception underpinning this Q:

> For performance reasons, I need to run the same operations over a millions times in as short a time as possible, which is why I am really obsessing over every tiny detail.

A [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is O(N²).  A clever bubble sort is still O(N²).  A simple change to the algorithm can get you down to O(N logN).  Moral: Algorithmic optimisations deliver big dividends; micro optimizations rarely do so and are usually counter productive as they can create unmaintainable code.

In the case of SQL optimization, replacing an loop of statements with a correctly indexed (join and) a single statement can give you an order of magnitude saving in runtime.

Replacing a PHP for loop with a Array function call can do likewise.

Comment: That explains it nicely.  Regarding your mention of SQL optimization, the processes are inserts.  Reading from a file (do some processing) then insert the interpreted lines.  5000 lines = 1 query with 5000 inserts.  I now have the code pretty optimal.  Only issue now is the performance of the mysql server and php running out of memory at 165k inserts lol, but I can figure that one out with some kind of distributed work loads.  Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: There is a per stmt and a per row overhead to inserts, so batching them up makes sense, but there's a rapid diminishing return on increasing batch size.  If you batch at 10K, then you shouldn't run out of memory as long you descope (eg. undef or reuse) variables after each batch. Optimising bulk loading is a subject in its own right.  Eg. disabling indexes around the insert because index update is more efficient in batches.  It might be better to spool to tmp file and do a LOAD DATA.